# So is that maximum?

Tags: code-golf, array

Given a map from arrays of integers of same size to single integers, determine if there is a set of indices such that the output is equal to the maximum of the elements at those indices for every corresponding pair.

You can take the input as a map if your language support, arrays of pairs, separated 2D array of input and its output, or other reasonable format. Shortest code wins.

### Test cases

```
input => output
input => output  ->  truthy/falsey

[1,2,3] => 2
[2,1,3] => 2
[3,2,1] => 3 -> true (maximum of pos 1 and pos 2)

[1,2,3] => 2
[2,3,1] => 2
[3,3,2] => 2 -> false (Whatever positions chosen, 3 must at least appeared in output)

[1,2,3] => 2 -> true (maximum of pos 2, or maximum of pos 1 and 2)

[1,2,3] => 0 -> false (no way maximum of some of 1, 2 and 3 result in 0)
```

Comment: Also, can we take input as a list of input lists and as a list of output values? e.g. `[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1]]` and `[2,2,3]`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing That input format should be acceptable

Comment: I've cleaned up the test cases a bit, as they were a bit difficult to "group" together, and copy/paste for testing

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ZŒPZ€Ṁ€€i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q6KSAqEdNax7ubACSQJT5//BypaOTHu6cAeRE/v8fHW2oY6RjHKsTbaRjCKaNgXzD2FgdBWQpY6AQSAoogiyFzPwPVAZWrgBmGIEZIMIgFgA)

Outputs `0` for falsey, non-zero for truthy

-3 bytes thanks to [hyper-neutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyper-neutrino)!

### How it works

```
ZŒPZ€Ṁ€€i - Main link. Takes a list of inputs I on the left and outputs O on the right
Z         - Transpose I
 ŒP       - Powerset of the columns
   Z€     - Transpose each
       €  - Over each column powerset:
     Ṁ€   -   Get the maximum of each column
        i - Index of O in this list of lists, or 0 if not found
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 70 bytes

Returns `false` for valid, or `true` for invalid.

```javascript
a=>a.some(b=([a,m])=>a.every((v,i)=>v-m|b[i],a.map((v,i)=>b[i]|=v>m)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY9BDoIwFET3XoQ2KUSo27r0BO6@XRQsiqGUUGxCwt1ra4BoIsTd/DeZzvQhrDBFV7V93OirdCVzgh1FYrSSKGcIBFEcByKt7AaELKn8aWM15lBxIhIl2pkGMjJ7VBhjV@jG6Fomtb6hCM7ds78PPMK7T14iAEhJRignGScAGUkXTT1PuT853kr9drmPBufLii4NnERt/tlBQ/e0gwax0jStXNbP2quN1NS133QPq397v@pe)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 28 bytes

```
Times@@Max/@(Sign[#-#2])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PyQzN7XYwcE3sULfQSM4Mz0vWllX2Sj2fX@7ptr/gKLMvBKggF2ag4NyrFpdcHJiXl01V3V1taGOkY5xrQ6XgkK1kY4hjGkMFDWsBbGBoiAFQCa6YmOgCqhioHKEYiMUxRBhTCEDTCGT2lqu2v8A)

Input `[inputs, outputs]`. Returns `0` for truthy, and nonzero (`1` or `-1`) otherwise.

```
             Sign[#-#2]     categorize indices for each i/o (-1 <, 0 =, 1 >)
       Max/@(          )   take max for each index across i/o s
Times@@                     0 present (solutions exist)?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
øæʒø€àQ
```

Port of [*@cairdCoinheringaahing*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235348/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

Outputs an empty list `[]` as falsey, and a non-empty list (containing one or multiple matrices of integers) as truthy.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8I7Dy05NOrzjUdOawwsC//@PjjbUMdIxjtWJNtIxBNPGQL5hbCwXUAAkAQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WmRDqYq@kkJiXoqBkHwFkPWqbBGT9P7zj8LJTkw7veNS05vCCiMD/tS726UcalNISc4pTKxVKikpLMiqVlIsPr1BS0Di8X1NJ5380EBjqGOkYx@pEG@kYgmljIN8wNlZHASgCkgGyFFCUGQOlQcqACuHKjFCVgYUxhQxiY2MB).

**Explanation:**

```python
ø        # Zip/transpose the (implicit) first input-matrix, swapping rows/columns
 æ       # Get the powerset of these columns
  ʒ      # Filter this list of matrices by:
   ø     #  Zip/transpose the current matrix, swapping rows/columns
    €    #  For each inner list:
     à   #   Pop and leave the maximum
      Q  #  Check if this list is equal to the (implicit) second input-list
         # (after which the filtered list of matrices is output implicitly as result)
```